# ESP8266 module cutting connection with PC via USB

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266

My Arduino UNO is connected directly to the ESP8266 (01) WiFi module. The Red and Blue LED flashes and it seems to work properly. But when I connect the UNO to my computer, the module refreshes at irregular intervals and the PC produces sounds as that of ejecting and inserting a USB. I don't know whether this is caused due to low voltage supplied from the USB or some other reason. Please help me out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At which pins you connected the ESP8266?
The pins pin 0 (RX) an 1 (TX) are connectet internaly to the FTDI USB-to-TTL Serial chip.
If you using Serial.begin() to communicate with the ESP8266, you can't communicate with the pc at the same time.
Use SoftwareSerial to communicate with the ESP8266 an Serial to PC.

It is also recommed to feed the ESP8266 with an external 3.3V power supply and stabilize with an capacitor. This could  produces the sounds of ejecting and inserting a USB.

Comment: I've used pin 0 and 1. Since I'm a newbie to Arduino can you please provide a link for using SoftwareSerial.

Comment: A tutorial for using SoftwareSerial can be found [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SoftwareSerialExample). For the code you can read [this](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/18575/20188). Also this [blog post](https://petestechprojects.wordpress.com/2014/11/30/connecting-esp8266-to-arduino/) could be helpful.