# How to change baudrate of ESP8266 (12e) permanently?

Tags: arduino-nano, esp8266, firmware, baud-rate

### IMPORTANT: DO NOT USE `AT+IPR=9600`! (see update)

I have an ESP8266 12E module that communicates at 115,200 bauds. Since I use it with an Arduino Nano with SoftwareSerial things get messy. So I found that I should reduce the baud rate of the ESP module.

I found [this link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/abhinaba/2016/01/23/esp8266-wifi-with-arduino-uno-and-nano/) on how to do it.

**I am wondering**

- Is this a permanent change or do you need to do this every time after the module is powered?
- Can I achieve the same by sending the command from the Arduino over SoftSerial? Well, I guess not since I tried and I always get an error on `AT+CIOBAUD=9600` or `AT+IPR=9600`.
- I read somewhere that in newer firmware versions of the ESP8266, the baud rate defaults to 9,600. Can anyone confirm this and if so, is it better to flash this newer firmware?

The module's vendor:

```
Ai-Thinker Technology Co.,Ltd.
```

I think the current version of the firmware is 0.3.0. If I send  `AT+GMR` I get:

```
sending AT+GMR

response: ?AT¥TJÕ¨H(Q�²•ÉÍ¥½¹é‚r¢‚r‚r‚BÕ��Â’‚ŠªŠ¢Ò¢ªÒªÂJm
 SDK versioo:0.3.0
 Ai�½½
 ‚Šj
```

Again some garbage because of the baud rate which is too high.

Other info on the module:

```
sending AT+RST
response: ?AT+RST
OK
WRT
"%M
<99CT
 ets Jan  8 2013,rst catse:2, boot lode:(3,7)
load 0x40100000ntail 4
chksum 0x89
ld tail 4
chm3 tail 8 r 0 aM
 ón't use rtc mem dat`
sl��oÌÿ
Ai-Thinker Technology Co.,Ltd.
```

**UPDATE**

(*) I used an FTDI232 module to send `AT+IPR=9600` to my ESP8266-12E module **and I bricked it**!

**DO NOT USE `AT+IPR=9600` ON AN ESP8266(-12E).**

I did not manage to recover it so far! I tried re-flashing it but I get Invalid head exceptions.

On a new module I sent the `AT+CIOBAUD=9600` command and it worked. Permanently!

My module specs:

```
AT+GMR 
AT version:0.40.0.0(Aug  8 2015 14:45:58)
SDK version:1.3.0
Ai-Thinker Technology Co.,Ltd.
Build:1.3.0.2 Sep 11 2015 11:48:04
OK
```

Comment: You could try the hardware serial?
Or pull the reset pin low and then talk to the ESP directly through USB.
Might check if those work.

Comment: @Paul: the nano has only one set of hardware serial ports. So if I use those I cannot send data to the Arduino Serial Monitor anymore, making it hard to understand what is happening... Guess I'll need to go for firmware upgrade.

Comment: well you could make use of the software serialport for debugging? You'll need a "usb-serial/ttl" cable though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34248581/set-baud-rate-to-esp8266-at-9600 This will answer your question.

Comment: Seems that setting the baud rate with **AT+IPR=9600 also bricks an ESP01**. I tried several suggestions in this thread to recover it. The solution in the link Marco Andre Silva supplied worked for me.

Comment: So you could "unbrick" your module?

Comment: This video, [1. How to flash ESP01 with latest AT command firmware](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QVhWVu8NnZc), helped me re-flash the firmware to my ESP01.

Comment: Has anyone worked out *why* that command appears to brick the ESP?  That seems really weird

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I Connected an FTDI232 module at 115200 baud and could read the specs of the ESP8266 module now:

```
AT+GMR 
AT version:0.40.0.0(Aug  8 2015 14:45:58)
SDK version:1.3.0
Ai-Thinker Technology Co.,Ltd.
Build:1.3.0.2 Sep 11 2015 11:48:04
OK
```

After that I sent the `AT+IPR=9600` command, which first seemed to do the trick.
But after reboot of the module, all I got was garbage response, at any baudrate.

**DO NOT SEND AT+IPR=9600 TO YOUR ESP8266(12e) MODULE**

Maybe the `AT+UART_DEF` command - as mentioned by JRobert - works, but I used the  `AT+CIOBAUD=9600` command and it worked. Permanently!

I hope this can help others.

Answer (score 13):

Depending on how recent a version of the AT Instruction Set interpreter your chip has, the two instructions you tried may not be valid ones; they are not listed in Espressif's [ESP8266 AT Instruction Set](https://www.espressif.com/en/file/721/download?token=5D4jCASk) document. Searches for either "CIOBAUD" or "IPR" in the current document (version 1.5.3) return no results.

The baud rate commands are now "AT+UART_CUR" and "AT+UART_DEF" which configure the entire UART for the current session or the current and future sessions, respectively. The manual's prototype for the command is:

```
AT+UART_DEF=<baudrate>, <databits>, <stopbits>, <parity>, <flow control>
Example:
AT+UART_DEF=115200, 8, 1, 0, 3
```

I have used these and can confirm that they work.

What I've found using software serial is that it can push 115200 baud well enough to send commands to the device (though I wouldn't build an application that depends on it) but it can only read reliably up to 9600 baud. I've been able to change my devices' baud rates from 115200 baud to 9600 over software serial; you just have to expect garbage coming back and ignore it:

```
// Set ESP8266 baud rate to 9600. You only need to do this once per device
set software serial baud to 115200;
send "AT+UART_DEF=9600,8,1,0,0";
set software serial baud to 9600;
// From now on, communicate with your device at 9600 baud.
```

Answer (score 4):

I bricked my Esp with the same command, too. After hours of searching I found a way to reset the bricked esp. https://developer.mbed.org/users/sschocke/code/WiFiLamp/wiki/Updating-ESP8266-Firmware I had to set the baudrate to 115200 instead of 9600, and between the uploading files I had to disconnect the esp from power. I hope that helps you and everybody who did the same and found your post over Google.

Comment: Power cycling the ESP between each file was the key thing to me too - other sites combine all the files into a single `esptool.py` command, but that did not work for me. Only after breaking it into individual commands, one per file, and cycling between each one, was I finally able to restore the AT firmware. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: Also, I tried using the `esptool.py` that comes with the ESP32 IDF (v2.1-beta1) and that one works successfully with a _single_ command to flash all files on my ESP8266 (which it also supports) - so only one power cycle + GPIO0-GND required.

Answer (score 1):

Using this firmware:
 https://developer.mbed.org/users/sschocke/code/WiFiLamp/wiki/Updating-ESP8266-Firmware

and this flasher:
http://yaab-arduino.blogspot.com.br/2015/12/flashing-esp8266-firmware-arduino.html
i was able to recover my esp 8266 12f

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are you are having power supply issue. What is your power supply rating ? and try adding a small capacitor between vcc and ground. 
Also its good idea to update the firmware to 0.9 which has baudrate issue fixed.

You can find new firmware at
https://github.com/espressif/esp8266_at

Comment: I don't think this is a power supply issue. I have an external power supply which is more than capable. I tried without before and then the Arduino kept restarting... I found on a forum that that was due to power supply issues. So now I'm fine there. I really think the issue is that the SoftSerial cannot cope with the 115k baudrate.

Comment: esp is really picky, add a small capacitor between vcc and ground. I also power mine from external power source and was experiencing restarts.