# I change ESP8266 baudrate and now it doesn't work

Tags: serial, esp8266, communication, linux, baud-rate

I was trying some AT commands using the monitor of the Arduino Web Editor with an Arduino Uno and a ESP8266 module. It was working at 115200 bauds but then I changed it with `AT+CIOBAUD=19200` and now it can't communicate.

How can I change the baudrate to 115200?

Now I see this:

[image: Monitor with weird characters.]

Comment: How were you "trying" those AT commands?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried setting the web editor's baud rate to both the old and the new values? I ask because the CIOBAUD command has been obsolete for a while now so, depending on the age of your device, it may have done nothing. The command was replaced by "AT+UART_CUR" and "AT+UART_DEF" which have a different syntax.

See [this answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/24156/how-to-change-baudrate-of-esp8266-12e-permanently/24191#24191) to a similar question.

Update:

Yes, here's an example:

```
// Declare a serial object to talk to ESP8266
SoftwareSerial EspSerial(WIFITX_PIN, WIFIRX_PIN);  // RX, TX

void setup(void){
   // Init WiFi serial
   EspSerial.begin(9600);
   delay(10);
}
```

I've used 9600 baud in my example since SoftwareSerial may not work well at faster speeds.

Update 2:

> Is it possible to send AT commands from the code instead of the
>   monitor?

Yes, easily. Once the above code has run (and note that I've deleted an unnecessary line since update 1), you can send strings to the ESP with EspSerial.print() and EspSerial.println(). Here's an AT command example:

```
// Set 9600 baud, standard 8-bit frame, and save as power-on default:
EspSerial.println("AT+UART_DEF=9600,8,1,0,0");
```

Comment: Is it possible to set baudrate inside the code with a sentence?

Comment: Is it possible to send AT commands from the code instead of the monitor?

Comment: your question has been answered. why are you posting new questions here?